# Issue with an old JQuery plugin upon migration to 3.0

Tags: jquery

I've updated to the latest version of JQuery (3.1.1) from 1.11. This old plugin is the only thing giving me trouble in the installation, and it hasn't been updated in a long time;

```
/**
 * jQuery Unveil
 * A very lightweight jQuery plugin to lazy load images
 * http://luis-almeida.github.com/unveil
 *
 * Licensed under the MIT license.
 * Copyright 2013 Luís Almeida
 * https://github.com/luis-almeida
 */

;(function($) {

  $.fn.unveil = function(threshold, callback) {

    var $w = $(window),
        th = threshold || 0,
        retina = window.devicePixelRatio > 1,
        attrib = retina? "data-src-retina" : "data-src",
        images = this,
        loaded;

    this.one("unveil", function() {
      var source = this.getAttribute(attrib);
      source = source || this.getAttribute("data-src");
      if (source) {
        this.setAttribute("src", source);
        if (typeof callback === "function") callback.call(this);
      }
    });

    function unveil() {
      var inview = images.filter(function() {
        var $e = $(this);
        if ($e.is(":hidden")) return;

        var wt = $w.scrollTop(),
            wb = wt + $w.height(),
            et = $e.offset().top,
            eb = et + $e.height();

        return eb >= wt - th && et <= wb + th;
      });

      loaded = inview.trigger("unveil");
      images = images.not(loaded);
    }

    $w.on("scroll.unveil resize.unveil lookup.unveil", unveil);

    unveil();

    return this;

  };

})(window.jQuery || window.Zepto);
```

The plugin constantly causes the following error when scrolling through the lazy loaded images in the page;

```
jquery-3.1.1.js:9793 Uncaught TypeError: a.indexOf is not a function
```

I can't manage to see the problem, it doesn't exactly jump to my eyes.

Comment: Are you using the minimized version of jQuery? Try to comment out your codes line by line to investigate which line caused the error

Comment: Observe the stacktrace of the error, and see it leads to your code, or this plugin's code.

Comment: I'm indeed using the minimized version with its map. And I did try to comment out every line of code, but I can't seem to pinpoint one exact line that causes the problem. I'm starting to think "(window.jQuery || window.Zepto);" is the problem.